# How to define and implement a filter function?

Tags: c, filter

How should one define and code a filter function in C? And predicates, at that?
(Readability more important than performance.)
I'd prefer not to *need* to explicitly specify element size.
The following untested code sketch looks verbose&clumsy enough to ask:

```c
typedef bool (*predicate)(void *data, void const *value);

/** Copy to out the elements e of in having wanted(data, e) true, 
 *  returning the number of elements copied.
 *  Indexes 0 [inclusive] to n [exclusive] better be valid for in,
 *  and out big enough. */
index filter_(predicate wanted, void *data, 
              void const *in, void *out, size_t n, size_t const element_size) {
    char const *cin = (char const *)in;
    char *cout = (char *)out;
    for (index i = 0, o = 0 ; ; i++, cin += element_size) {
        if (n <= i)
            return o;
        if (wanted(data, cin)) {
            memcpy(cout, cin, element_size);
            out += element_size;
        }
    }
/* return -1;  // not reached */
}

#define element_count(array) (sizeof (array)/sizeof (array)[0])
#define filter_array(wanted, in, out) filter(wanted, in, out, element_count(in))
#define filter(wanted, in, out, n) filter_(wanted, in, out, n, sizeof *(in))

/* example predicate: */
bool greater(void *data, void *value) {
    return *(int*)value > *(int*)data;
}
```

Comment: You *must* specify element size, otherwise how would the function know how much to increase the pointers? Or how much to copy?

Comment: `char const *in = (char *)in;` ... This is not going to work...

Comment: Also, `predicate`, `int_predicate` as a type, and `int_predicate` as a variable? Even for a [mre] to show us, please try to keep unrelated errors or problems at a minimum.

Comment: You could define a struct holding both the predicate function and a copy function for a specific data type. That copy function must either also advance the in and out pointers or you could add another type specific function to iterate over your arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The implementation needs an element size. I tried to mitigate adverse effects with the macros.

Comment: `char const *in = (char const *)in;` This ain't gonna work either.

Comment: You can't "overload" macros. And `sizeof (in)/sizeof *(in)` will not work if `in` is a pointer.

Comment: ((note to self) I know about as well that comments aren't answers as I suppose the commentors know a question not to be a supposed solution.)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `sizeof (in)/sizeof *(in) will not work if in is a pointer` I remembered that much (didn't code C in earnest for a quarter century). That's what the four parameter macro was for - I hate the idea of coming up with different names.

Comment: (I may be spoiled by Python's `[e for e in sequence if wanted(e)]`. Or the new-fangled `filter(wanted, sequence)`)